# Route PHP requests to subfolders in App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

To deploy a php app to Google App Engine it says that you need a router, like something in Laravel...the problem is I don't use Laravel (or any other major PHP framework) and I have no intention to. I need to know how to route requests to the appropriate paths in just vanilla PHP. I haven't found any tutorials online that don't deal with a framework or just including client views. Here is what I need:
When a request comes into '/'...it routes to /index.php (obviously this is already happening)

When a request comes into '/account/' it routes to `/account/index.php`. This is the part I don't know how to do.

I have tried outputting `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and then redirecting the path to the correct place, but `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` always just reads '/'.

Comment: You can handle requests in your PHP code any way you want. The term "router" is just a framework to automate this in frameworks like Laravel. The REQUEST_URI will match the part you put in the browser. For example `www.example.com/home.html` results in the URI being `/home.html`. This is very basic PHP coding for websites. Google Search for examples, there are lots in just raw PHP.

Comment: @JohnHanley But REQUEST_URI isn't returning what I put into the browser...as stated above, if I put in example.com/hello/ it returns just '/' . It's like all request are automatically routed back to the root. And I know how to do default PHP routing in nginx by defining your root and location vars, it just doesn't look like App Engine gives you that basic access

Comment: This is defined by the PHP spec: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php If you are not seeing the correct value, then there is something else going on. You will need to show your complete code and the full browser request. Include the version of PHP, etc.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the nginx config and particularly in the [fastCGI parameters](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/) and edit it appropriately. 

You can also check the $_SERVER from the url you're testing to check if there is any other variable with the info that you need.